# Canvas/HTML5 : Track path position

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I would like to make the ball roll on the path I draw, but I have no idea how to do this. I tried to push the new coordonates of that path in an array in order to make a soustraction of the canvas.height minus the position of the path but I don't see how to make it to work... Here is a fiddle to see the demo. (you can use your keyboard to move)

Any help is welcome, thanks ! 
https://jsfiddle.net/jahu3bkg/3

edit : to see what Im looking for, Im trying to make something like this game : http://canvasrider.com/ !

EDIT2: no one to give me another hint? :( I saw that I could build a context from an array of numbers where block = 1 and empty space = 0, and then I can count the collisions but this doesn't seem handy, and again, Im pretty sure this isn't what Canvas rider or Line Rider are using :(

My JS here :

```
window.requestAnimationFrame||window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame;

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var ballRadius = 10;
var W = canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
var H = canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
var x = 50;
var y = 500;
var velX = 0;
var velY = 0;
var gravity = 0.2;
var speed = 2;
var friction = 0.99;

var coordinates = [
  {x: 120, y : 200},
  {x : 250, y : 300},
  {x : 350, y : 300},
  {x : 350, y : 315},
  {x : 370, y : 315},
  {x : 370, y : 330},
  {x : 390, y : 330},
  {x : 390, y : 345},
  {x : 410, y : 345},
  {x : 410, y : 360},
  {x : 430, y : 360},
  {x : 550, y : 400},
  {x : 950, y : 400}
];

var rightPressed = false;
var leftPressed = false;
var upPressed = false;
var downPressed = false;
var pressed = {};

document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownHandler, false);
document.addEventListener("keyup", keyUpHandler, false);

  window.onkeydown = function(e) {
  if ( pressed[e.which] ) return;
  pressed[e.which] = e.timeStamp;
  };

  window.onkeyup = function(e) {
  if ( !pressed[e.which] ) return;
  var duration = ( e.timeStamp - pressed[e.which] ) / 1000;
  pressed[e.which] = 0;
  console.log(duration);
  };

function keyUpHandler(e) {
  if(e.keyCode == 39) {
    rightPressed = false;
  }
  else if(e.keyCode == 37) {
    leftPressed = false;
  }
  else if(e.keyCode == 38) {
    upPressed = false;
  }
  else if(e.keyCode == 40) {
    downPressed = false;
  }
}
function keyDownHandler(e) {
  if(e.keyCode == 39) {
    rightPressed = true;
  }
  else if(e.keyCode == 37) {
    leftPressed = true;
  }
  else if(e.keyCode == 38) {
    upPressed = true;
  }
  else if(e.keyCode == 40) {
    downPressed = true;
  }
}
function Ball() {

  this.draw = function(ctx) {
    ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, ballRadius, 0, Math.PI*2, false);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
  }
}

var ball = new Ball();
var newCord = {};
function draw() {
  var pos = {x: 0, y: 0};
  function line() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgb(0,0,0)';
    ctx.lineWidth = 4;

    for (var i =0; i < coordinates.length; i++) {
      ctx.moveTo(pos.x,pos.y);
      pos = coordinates[i];
      ctx.lineTo(pos.x,pos.y);
    }
    ctx.stroke();
  }
  var newCord = { xl:canvas.width - pos.y, yl: canvas.height - pos.x}

  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, W, H);

  velY *= friction;
  y += velY;
  velX *= friction;
  x += velX;

  if (x >= canvas.width) {
      x = 0;
  }

  if (y > canvas.height - ballRadius || y < ballRadius) {
    velY = -velY;
    y = canvas.height - ballRadius;
  }

  if(x + velX > canvas.width-ballRadius || x < ballRadius) {
      velX = 2;
  }

  velY += gravity;

  if(upPressed) {
    if (velY > -speed) {
            velY--;
        }
  }
  if(downPressed) {
    if (velY < speed) {
           velY++;
       }
  }
  if (rightPressed) {
    if (velX < speed) {
            velX++;
        }
  }
  if (leftPressed) {
    if (velX > -speed) {
            velX--;
        }
  }

  line();
  ball.draw(ctx);

};

draw();
```

Comment: You need to define the path as polygons and then use an algorythm for collision, the best for 2D game is the SAT, if you give it a read here it might really help you http://www.dyn4j.org/2010/01/sat/. Also why not use an API with everything ready for you to make a game? Phaser.io is fast, has a ton of features and It's FREE! https://phaser.io/

Comment: Im not sure that this is what I want... I don't really want polygons but paths drawn within canvas ! see my edit, Im sure these doesn't use sat, also I don't wanna use any API, Im making this for purpose, so I can learn and see things... :D Thanks for the hints tho !!

Comment: You want something like Line Rider... The problem here is if you want an object to collide with a drawn lines you'll need to do pixel-based collision detection, which is precise but slow. My suggestion is to show the drawing but use lines (x1,y1,x2,y2) for collision. I found a tutorial here that shows how to make a linerider game http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2007/02/03/create-a-flash-draw-game-like-line-rider-or-others-part-2/. And this one explains how line-collision works http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/7211/point-line-collision-reaction. This is all the help I can offer, sorry

Comment: Yes ahaha Line rider :D Ok thanks for all of this, Im gonna have a look !

Comment: That website is a mine of information :D ! thanks for that !